# Wordpress Tiny MCE change default selected editor

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, default

How can I select the default editor to be shown between the HTML and the Visual editors?

Currently the Visual editor is always selected by default and I want that the HTML editor is selected when the page loads instead.

Comment: Check its documentation. There should be a parameter that can set.

Comment: @WilliamK: Hi, thanks for your help. Can you help me with the search? I'm not able to find anything on this :( Also, put your answer as is and not as a comment to I can give you credit! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sould do it. Add this line in your themes `functions.php`. Replace `"html"` with `"tinymce"` if you like to switch back.

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "html";') );
```

Comment: Wow! Simple awesome! Thanks! Altought I tested your code and always selected the Visual tab, with the following code I managed to select the Text tab by default `add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "html";') );`. I found the ´html´ parameter in the ´/wp-admin/js/editor.js´ file.